# The anti-forgery token Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, antiforgerytoken

I am using MVC 5 , published on web host when post to db i got this error :

> The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the  configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

i tried add :

```
 <machineKey decryptionKey="AutoGenerate, IsolateApps" 
            validationKey="AutoGenerate, IsolateApps" />
```

but not worked ..
any help i would be thankful

Answer (score 1):

As error message said, you will need to provide machine key. *For example,*

```
<machineKey validationKey="ABCD1234..." 
     decryptionKey="DEFG1234..." validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
```

There are few ways to generate machine key.

- [Easiest way to generate MachineKey](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amb/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey/)
- [ASP.Net MachineKey Generator](http://www.allkeysgenerator.com/Random/ASP-Net-MachineKey-Generator.aspx)